# Adding an apostrophe before text in non-empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a simple macro that would add an postrophe " ' " before text in cells if they ar not empty. I.e.:

This:
Column C
ASDF
FDSA

FASADA

Should change into this:
Column C
'ASDF
'FDSA

'FASADA

My code looks like that: (but there is an error in penultimate line (the very lest one if one wouldn't count the "End Sub" line)

```
Sub Inserting_apostrophe()
startrow = 1
endrow = 1800

For x = startrow To endrow
    If Cells(x, "C").Value <> "" Then
    Range("C" & x).Value = "'" & "Cells(x, "C").Value" 'This line is unfortunately wrong, could you mend it?

End Sub
```

Thank You All in advance,
with regards,
Artur Rutkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Cells(x, "C").Value"` is the problem. It should not be in quotes.
You also did not complete your `If` statement or `For` statement. Use `End If` and `Next` to end your `If` statement and tell `For` when to loop.

```
Sub Inserting_apostrophe()
    Dim startrow as Integer
    Dim endrow as Integer
    Dim x as Integer

    startrow = 1
    endrow = 1800

    For x = startrow To endrow
        If Cells(x, 3).Value <> "" Then
            Range("C" & x).Value = "'" & Cells(x, 3).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately this is not the case, I just misspelled my question - I am terriably sorry for that! The line with comment is simply wrong... But I don't how to write it correctly...

Comment: Thank you! I have just noticed it! You are great. One silly mistake of mine... Many thanks!